# CSS design question - adding a small background-image for div in a specific position

Tags: javascript, css

To clarify, I made the following diagram:

[image: diagram]

Basically I have a bordered div, which is clickable. After clicking it, I want to (through javascript) create a new div which has a protruding arrow shaped border into the clicked div.

Any ideas as to how I would create such a border? I'm not worried about the javascript. Just how to actually create such a border.

Comment: Make the triangle as an image with transparent background and same color as div. Use JS to show/hide/position image over div.

Comment: Maybe you'll find somethin interesting here: http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/stylish-jquery-tooltip-plugins-webdesign/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to make it as *close* to your <strike>drawing</strike> beautiful diagram as possible, but I wasn't quite able to get the arrow's hrm... *unique* angle.

http://jsfiddle.net/WJtnM/

#### HTML

```
<div id="b"> <span class="g">BEFORE CLICK</span>&nbsp; 
    <div id="f"> AFTER CLICK </div>
    <div class="c" id="d"></div>
    <div class="c" id="e"></div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
#b
{
    position:relative;
    padding:28px 20px 12px 60px;
    width:170px;
    border:1px solid black;
}
.c
{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:100%;
    right:30px;

    width:0px;
    height:0px;
    border: 20px solid transparent;
}
.c#d
{
    border-bottom-color: black;
}
.c#e
{
    border-bottom-color: white;
    margin-bottom: -1px;
}

#f
{
    position:absolute;
    padding:35px 20px 12px 60px;
    width:170px;
    border:1px solid black;
    border-bottom-width: 0px;
    bottom:100%;
    left:-1px;
}
```

#### jQuery

```
$("#b").click(function(){

    $(".c,#f,.g").toggle();

})
```

Comment: i might have to accept this answer simply because of your joke

Comment: if it dosen't, it just my fault

Answer (score 2):

You can use the CSS Triangle approach (Lots of examples online, [here's  one from CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/)), where you have an empty `div` inside your tooltip that uses some clever border manipulation to make the angle.  Just position the `div`, and you're done!

Answer (score 1):

Check out the below example, after clicking the link either you append the "after-click-div" or show it. The arrow div is positioned with negative margin over the border.

```
<div class="container">
  <a href="#">Link</a>
  <div id="after-click-div" style="border: 1px solid #000; position: relative;">
    <div class="arrow" style="background: #fff url(arrow.gif) no-repeat; position: absolute; top: -10px; right: 10px; width: 10px; height: 10px"></div>
   content
  </div>
</div>
```

Or you can save an image like this ***_*__*_*__**^_ and assign it as a background image to the after_click_div like `background: url(arrow.gif) no-repeat top right`

Answer (score 0):

The arrow border have to be an image and it have to take a z-index.